# Open PDF in presentation mode on every browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, presentation

I have problem with opening PDF in fullscreen mode and presentation mode (this last is very important for me).

This code works only on Internet Explorer:

`onclick="window.open('{{ child.url }}', 'fs','fullscreen'); return false;"`

I need to make this working on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Egde.

Or maybe someone know how make scrolling pages by mouse scroll?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to override the user's preferences? Stop that nonsense, and allow the user to pick how s/he wants to use PDFs. Most modern browsers allow to preview the file in the browser, but some might have set it to auto-download, for instance, instead. Don't push "this is the solution" on users, allow them to use the programs they use, without overriding the choices they make. A simple `<a href="link_to_pdf">` will do just fine.

Comment: It's a joice of my client, not mine.

But what about scrolling mouse just like in presentation mode but in normal view after open PDF ? It's posible ?

Comment: You can't.

You may be able to remove the chrome of the browser but you won't be able to put the PDF into presentation mode. Not all PDF Viewers even have presentation mode. It works in IE because you probably have Adobe Reader installed. Chrome, Safari, and Edge use their own PDF viewer that you don't behave like Adobe Reader.